# How to detect memory leaks in Azure worker role on local machine

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

I have `Azure SDK 2.5` .I need to detect memory leaks in worker role that runs tasks. What type of profiler could you advise to me ?

Also, how can i download memory dumps to analyse from production environment ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should upgrade your Azure SDK to the latest 2.9 version.

To debug your worker role locally, you can just press F5 to start VS in Debug mode, and if you have VS 2015, it already has Memory and CPU profiler that you can use.
There are many other profilers like DebugDiag, and Ants Profiler

If you want to debug an Azure Worker or Web Role, then expand the list of resources in VS under your Azure Subscription and right click on the worker role and select Debug, but make sure the remote debugging is enabled in the worker role settings.

See this link for more details

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines/

Comment: I use VS 2013, i can not migrate to 2.9

Comment: There is Azure SDK 2.9 for VS2013, maybe you have to install Update 3 

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/

Comment: I can't migrate my projects because our team works with 2.5, i need to analyse RAM consuming for worker on the local computer

Comment: This is a link that explains exactly how you analyse your memory issues using WinDbg https://greenfinch.ie/blog/2016-05-04-windbg.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Haitham!

Comment: But how can i monitor RAM usage in dynamic of worker role in Azure ?